# How to filter the result of a batchGet from Google Sheets API?

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to filter the rows on a batchGet operation using Google Sheets API and return only rows that don't have a specific value. Does anyone know how to do this in java?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the [ConditionType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#conditiontype) `BLANK`.

> The cell's value must be empty. Supported by conditional formatting
>   and filters. Requires no [ConditionValues](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#BooleanCondition.FIELDS.values).

Additional reference: [FilterCriteria](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria).

> Criteria for showing/hiding rows in a filter or filter view.

Two required filed for this are `hiddenValues[]` and `condition`.

Comment: But these assume that you have write access to the sheet to be able to apply the filter right? I only have view access, and I am not sure the  FilterCriteria could be used with a  get or a batchGet request